# maven: set property in/from plugin's pom.xml and access it in pom.xml which calls the plugin. how?

Tags: maven

i'm trying to set a property from a plugin it's pom.xml and access that property from the plugin-caller-pom.xml which calls that plugin. but the tries with different plugin like antrun (script::javascript) or properties-maven-plugin or maven-surefire-plugin were all not successfull.
have some one tried that before and can tell me the way, how to do this?
Thank you very much.
Regards

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: hi,
i'm trying to build a list of information strings for my maven project. each plugin is also from us, so have the code for them. each plugin should fill the list with an information string. and after all plugin have been run. the maven project which run these plugins should then have the list with filled information and do something with that list. each plugin can also call another plugins recursively.